# Prevent getdate_r from filling in data it doesn't know

Tags: c, date, parsing, time

I am using [getdate_r](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_440.html) in a C program to parse user inputted time. A problem I am finding is that it is filling my `struct tm` with current time data for any missing data. For example, if a user enters "Dec 1" it correctly puts these values into the `struct tm`, however fields like the hour, minutes, and seconds also are filled and are filled with the current time.

How can I prevent this from happening? I'd rather those values be `NULL` so that I can do later checks for these missing fields. When no time is entered I want to make the hour, minutes and seconds maxed out (`23:59:59`) but now I am unable to detect this without manually parsing the string to see if the time data is included which kind of defeats the purpose of using `getdate_r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected as documented in the man page. I suggest using a predefined string and then overwrite the predefined string with the input data. The predefined string and the user input should be in the same format.

Example:

```
memset(strfmt, <len>, 0). /* or fill with the date required */
memcpy(strfmt, userinput, <len of user input>).
```